# Unable to get Spring's DataIntegrityViolationException after update to Hibernate Validator 4

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

I can't understand why I'm not getting a DataIntegrityViolationException any more after upgrading from Hibernate Validator 3.X to 4.X.

Somehow Spring is not able to wrap the persistence layer exceptions anymore.

Nothing has changed except the Validator dependency but the test validating that DataIntegrityViolationException is thrown in case of validation violation doesn't pass anymore.
I now get a javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException instead.

Everything is still in place, including of course the 

but translation doesn't happen anymore.

help welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to JPA-2.0 specification, JSR-303 validation is automatically triggered before persisting an entity if JSR-303 validator implementation (i.e. Hibernate Validator 4.x) is present in the classpath.

So, your entity is rejected by Hibernate Validator and don't get into the database, thus database integrity constraint is not violated and `DataIntegrityViolationException` is not thrown, and you get JSR-303's `ConstraintViolationException` instead.

You can disable this default behaviour by adding

```
<validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
```

to your `persistence.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

It blows my mind, but you're kind of right.

If I turn off validation I still get the 'validation', and instead of getting the `DataIntegrityViolationException` root cause `PropertyValueException`, I get `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException`, not even the expected `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException`

So it looks like there's 2 kinds of validation enabled by Hibernate Validator. What you seem to indicate is that the one enabled by default by the new Bean Validation is 'pre database'. 
But anyway, with or without `<validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>`, my logs always shows the queries. Could be that they don't make it to the database because of Hibernate logging, but I'm kind of lost about what is happening really.

What's the difference between the validation without `<validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>` and the validation with. Haven't found anything about that in the doc AFAIK.