# Spring - Different test results when running from JUnit and Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, junit

I am facing a problem I don't know how to solved. I am developing a Spring MVC application with its unit&integration tests. Everything **runs fine under JUnit** (Run As -> JUnit Test) **but fails** when I it **under Maven** (Surefire 2.10) I got two type of errors:

**Model Test**

```
testFileNameCannotBeNull(es.kazbeel.geckobugtracker.model.AttachmentTest): Unexpected exception, expected<org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException> but was<org.hibernate.PropertyValueException>
```

**Controller test**

```
testCreateEnvironmentPost_withBindingResultErrors(es.kazbeel.geckobugtracker.web.controller.admin.EnvironmentControllerTest): View name expected:</admin/environments/CreateEnvironment> but was:<redirect:/admin/environments/ViewEnvironments>
```

**AttachmentTest** (only the method that fails)

```
@Test(expected = ConstraintViolationException.class)
@DatabaseSetup("AttachmentTest.xml")
@Transactional
public void testFileNameCannotBeNull () {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Issue issue = (Issue) session.get(Issue.class, 1);
    User author = (User) session.get(User.class, 1);

    Attachment attch = AttachmentBuilder.attachment()
                                        .withIssue(issue)
                                        .withAuthor(author)
                                        .withFileName(null)
                                        .withFileSize(new Long(0))
                                        .withFileMimeType("file_mimetype")
                                        .build();

    session.save(attch);
    session.flush();
    session.clear();
}
```

In this case, the model is configured in a *hbm.xml*. The property is as follows

```
<property generated="never" lazy="false" length="255" name="fileName" column="FILE_NAME" not-null="true" type="java.lang.String">
```

**EnvironmentControllerTest** (only the method that fails)

```
@Test
public void testCreateEnvironmentPost_withBindingResultErrors () throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(post("/admin/environments/CreateEnvironment").param("name", ""))
           .andExpect(view().name("/admin/environments/CreateEnvironment"))
           .andExpect(model().hasErrors())
           .andExpect(model().size(1))
           .andExpect(model().attributeExists("environment"));

    verify(issueService, never()).saveEnvironment(any(Environment.class));
}
```

**EnvironmentController** (only method)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/CreateEnvironment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createEnvironmentPost (@Valid @ModelAttribute("environment") Environment environment,
                                     BindingResult result) {

    LOG.debug("Creating new Environment");

    if (result.hasErrors() == true) {
        LOG.debug("The environment is not valid: {}", result.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage());

        return CREATE_URL;
    }

    try {
        issueService.saveEnvironment(environment);
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
        LOG.debug(ex.getMessage());

        return CREATE_URL;
    }

    return "redirect:" + VIEW_URL;
}
```

**pom.xml** (only related to surefire)

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-test</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Sincerely, I am lost (I don't even know what kind of information should I show you regarding this problem).

Has anyone an idea of what might be happening? I haven't found anything similar surfing on the Internet.

**!  UPDATE !**

Removing the dependency (see below) in pom.xml (but keeping `javax.validation`) I get the same exceptions running the tests under JUnit.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

OK! This is a step ahead but, this makes me wonder whether [this assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7804438/815227) is true. I was convinced that validation is the very first verification/check but it seems Hibernate's properties' check takes over firstly. Am I right?

Comment: Are you sure that in both cases tests are running using the same environments (are pointed to the same databases etc)?

Comment: IDE classpath might be "wider" than maven classpath. Check that you have correct dependency on pom.xml to validator library you are using.

Comment: I once runned in a problem in maven tests because of side effect with static values. Different tests used the same class, and it broke in every other than first one because some variable had kept previous initialization. But there is too much magic (for me) in Spring testing framework to know if it is relevant here

Comment: It appears that the order how the validator classes are loaded are different in Maven and Eclipse. How many validators do you have in your classpath?

Comment: We have previously had some problems with hibernate-validator 5.x compatibility when deployed. Could you test with older version, say 4.3.2.Final for example.

Comment: @MoritzPetersen: I have hibernate-validator 5.1.1.Final and javax.vallidation 1.1.0.Final.

Comment: @ikettu: Same problems :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### ! SOLVED !

**First**

**Problem**. It seems that the is a kind of incompatibility when including both validators in the same project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Solution**. I removed the `javax.validation` from the *pom.xml*.

NOTE: Please, if I am wrong I would really appreciate an explanation.

**Second**

**Problem**. After solving the first problem I still didn't get the tests running successfully.

**Solution**. I found the solution on the official [webpage](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/) of Hibernate Validator.

> Unified Expression Language (EL) Hibernate Validator also requires an
>   implementation of the Unified Expression Language (JSR 341) for
>   evaluating dynamic expressions in constraint violation messages. When
>   your application runs in a Java EE container such as WildFly, an EL
>   implementation is already provided by the container. In a Java SE
>   environment, however, you have to add an implementation as dependency
>   to your POM file. For instance you can add the following two
>   dependencies to use the JSR 341 reference implementation:

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```